# Codeigniter 2.1 $this->input->set_cookie($some_var); NOT WORKING

Tags: cookies, codeigniter-2, setcookie

I started creating a custom library that i would load for checking if user is logged in and also for registering users. Registration not started yet, but that's not important...

here's the problematic part.. **it WON't set cookies:**

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$some_value= 'asd';
$some_cookie_array = array(
                          'name'   => 'some_name',
                          'value'  => $some_value,
                          'expire' => 86500,
                          'secure' => TRUE
                          );
$this->input->set_cookie($some_cookie_array);
```

here is the full code for now:
[codepad.org/FILlq2qR](http://codepad.org/FILlq2qR)

This is how i call the library and check if user is logged in:

```
$this->load->library('user_management');
$login_data = $this->user_management->login();
var_dump($login_data);
```

Any help is more than welcome!

Cheers!

Comment: Might i add that I'm still new at CI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone on the CodeIgniter Forum helped. The reason was that I was using `'secure' => TRUE` which is only for https.

Comment: I had enabled CSRF protection, but was not using CI's form helper (manually setting the hidden field). CSRF wasn't working for me because of my cookie settings were set to 'secure' => TRUE. Your tip helped fix that!