# Codeigniter cookies not setting?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

After trying unsuccesfully for quite a while to get cookies set using codeigniter, i made this simple test to make sure they work. I read CI's documentation on cookies and found it rather lacking. Someone please tell me whats wrong?

```
 $this->input->set_cookie('test', 'testing a lot');

 echo $this->input->cookie('test');
```

Yes i am loading the cookie helper.

Comment: Is this line anywhere in your script? `$this->load->helper('cookie');`

Comment: Similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550389/codeigniter-2-1-this-input-set-cookiesome-var-not-working

Comment: can you show us your cookie settings please?

Comment: try the get_cookie() method ?

Comment: I tried the get_cookie() method. What cookie settings? in the config file?

Comment: yes Dylan - all the cookie settings in the config file

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to load the cookie helper if you aren't going to use the short hand function alias.

Check your cookie setting in the config.php file.  Especially:

```
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
```

If that doesn't work, just use the PHP's native function to set cookies and you probably can still use CI's input() to retrieve them.

```
setcookie("name", $value);
```